# C: Break Loop on Empty Input

Tags: c

So I'm writing a program that will loop forever, accepting string inputs until the user just presses enter with no string (along the way, I'm tracking the longest/shortest strings entered).  I have this loop:

```
char stringIn[1000] = {'\0'};
while(1)  {
    scanf("%[^\n]s", stringIn);
    if(stringIn[0] == '\0') {
        break;
    }

    if(strlen(stringIn) > strlen(longString)) {
        longString == stringIn;
    } else if (strlen(stringIn) < strlen(shortString))  {
        shortString == stringIn;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Currently this just loops forever. I'm still really new to C, but to me this looks like it should've worked.

Comment: `longString == stringIn` does nothing.  If it did make an assignment, it would be assigning longString to the same address  every time and get overwritten on the next read.  If you want to make a copy of the input string, use `strcpy` or `strncpy` or similar.

Comment: nit: it doesn't "do nothing", it checks if longString is equal to stringIn and evaluates to 0 or non-zero, but has no effect on the outcome of the program.  Although most likely the compiler will optimize it away and it will actually do nothing.

Comment: The use of `scanf` is also incorrect. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: try [this](https://ideone.com/tsvMdg)

Comment: How does `scanf` accept RegEx??? I can't understand it!

Comment: @iBug It's not regex, it's a scanset, and it's part of the `scanf` format string (see [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf))

Comment: @interjay If an empty return is pressed the fgets will write `\n` into the buffer if that happens the user has to check for the newline also otherwise the current logic will fail.

Comment: @0decimal0 The current logic already fails. Using scanf is wrong because it doesn't skip the newline.

Comment: Note that [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) scan sets using `%[…]` are complete; the `s` afterwards is just a literal character, not part of the conversion specification.  Your format string looks for an arbitrary sequence of non-newlines, and only stops when it _does_ encounter a newline (or EOF).  The next character, by definition is not an `s` (it's a newline, or EOF has been reached), so the match against `s` fails.  But there's no way for `scanf()` to report that matching failure; you can never tell when trailing context doesn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points to note:

1. You probably mistook the `==` operator for `=`, which is assignment. Even so, it wouldn't work because here it would only copy addresses of buffers (which get overwritten) (actually in my code it would throw a compile time errors). For copying strings you wanna use `strcpy`.
2. `scanf` is pretty vulnerable to buffer overflows and leaves the delimiter in the buffer. `fgets` is a much better choice for reading lines as it takes a buffer length as argument (check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) out).
3. `scanf` fills a number of items in it's list until characters matching the format string are read. If no chars match, then it doesn't fill `stringIn`, and hence doesn't append a `'\0'` at the end, and that's why your code never goes to `break;`. Instead we can use the return value, which is the number of items of the list that it fills (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)).

Anyway, here is code that does what you want:

```
int main() {
    char stringIn[1000] = "";
    char longString[2000] = "", shortString[2000] = "";
    int read, firstFlag = 0;
    while(1)  {
        read = scanf("%[^\n]", stringIn);
        if (read == 0) {
            break;
        }
        // to consume the '\n' left by scanf in the buffer
        getchar();

        if (!firstFlag || strlen(stringIn) > strlen(longString)) {
            strcpy(longString, stringIn);
        } 
        if (!firstFlag || strlen(stringIn) < strlen(shortString))  {
            strcpy(shortString, stringIn);
        }
        firstFlag = 1;
    }    

    printf("%s, %s\n", longString, shortString);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Edited according to Jonathan Leffler's comment above, correcting the use of the scanset.

Comment: `strlen(stringIn) < strlen(shortString)` never become true.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, that totally got away from me. Fixed.

Comment: `scanf` takes `\n` as input when the user input return key assuming that he has entered empty string, so it contains that and when user check for `str[0]` it doesn't contain the null terminator instead it contains the `\n`.

Comment: The first entry should be copied to both `longString` and `shortString`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Right you are again, thanks. (I'm new at this).

Comment: @0decimal0 Actually no the delimeters are left unread in the stream buffer. `stringIn` in that case will contain the previously read string, exactly.

Comment: yeah ! yeah! the next read would contain the newline character.